# Upload Sound Files to Cassandra Server?

Tags: database, file, audio, cassandra, pycassa

is it possible to upload sound files to the Cassandra server through Python, and then retrieve them again? If so, how would I go about doing it? I'm not to familiar with how Cassandra works, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

In addition, I am using pycassa as my python driver.

Thank you.

Comment: That's a bad idea. See https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#large_file_and_blob_storage

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this -- what you need is an hex representation of your song bytes. 
Take care on your blob size, from official documentation

> "A single column value may not be larger than 2GB; in practice,
>   "single digits of MB" is a more reasonable limit, since there is no
>   streaming or random access of blob values. "

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: How exactly does this work? I'm a newbie to these types of things, so a more in-depth answer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!